# Excel VBA Command Button code doesn't recognize object variable

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I've written the following code for a Command Button to add the (text) contents of a UserForm to an existing (named) dynamic range "MasterTable":

```
Private Sub AddDev_Click()

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    With Worksheets("Table").Range("MasterTable").ListObject.ListRows.Add
         .Offset(1, 0).Value = NewDevRecord.NewCorp.Value
         .Offset(1, 1).Value = NewDevRecord.NewAddr.Value
         .Offset(1, 1).Value = NewDevRecord.NewFac.Value
    End With

End Sub
```

When I populate the for and click the button, it throws `Error 91- Object Variable or With Block Variable Not Set` and highlights `Worksheets("Table").Range("MasterTable")`as the offender.  Isn't this a valid way to reference a range?  It works in my vba book and sheet modules--Do the UserForm components not have access?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe when calling a named range, you can just use `With Range("MasterTable")...`

Answer (score 0):

If `MasterTable` has been created as a `ListObject` then you would refer to it as:

```
Worksheets("Table").ListObjects("MasterTable")
```

So this code would work:

```
Private Sub AddDev_Click()

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    With Worksheets("Table").ListObjects("MasterTable").ListRows.Add
         .Offset(1, 0).Value = NewDevRecord.NewCorp.Value
         .Offset(1, 1).Value = NewDevRecord.NewAddr.Value
         .Offset(1, 1).Value = NewDevRecord.NewFac.Value
    End With

End Sub
```